# How can I make both hands fingers change by adding another enum mode?

Tags: unity, c#

A bit long but this scripts are connected to each other. I will explain the exact things I'm trying to add/change.

This is the controller script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Serialization;

    /*
     * Asset stores key control config.
     */
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
    public class HandController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private HandPosePresetsAsset m_preset;
        [SerializeField] private HandType m_handType = HandType.LeftHand;
        [SerializeField] private HandPoseData m_handPoseData;

        private HandRuntimeControl m_runtimeControl;
        private Avatar m_avatar;

        private HandPoseData m_basePose;

        public HandType Hand
        {
            get { return m_handType; }
            set
            {
                m_handType = value;
                InitializeRuntimeControl();
            }
        }

        public HandPosePresetsAsset Preset
        {
            get => m_preset;
            set => m_preset = value;
        }

        private void Awake()
        {
            InitializeRuntimeControl();
            #if UNITY_EDITOR
            
            #endif
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set current hand pose as base pose for transformation. 
        /// </summary>
        public void SetCurrentAsBasePose()
        {
            m_basePose = m_handPoseData;
        }        
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Set base hand pose from currently assigned preset 
        /// </summary>
        public void SetBasePoseFromCurrentPreset(string poseName)
        {
            m_basePose = m_preset[poseName];
        }        

        /// <summary>
        /// Set base hand pose from currently assigned preset 
        /// </summary>
        public void SetBasePoseFromCurrentPreset(int index)
        {
            m_basePose = m_preset[index];
        }        
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Set base hand pose.
        /// </summary>
        public void SetBasePose(ref HandPoseData pose)
        {
            m_basePose = pose;
        }        
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Set hand pose.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="poseName">name of pose in RuntimeHandPosePresetAsset.</param>
        /// <param name="t">lerp value of hand pose. 0.0f=base pose, 1.0f=poseName pose</param>
        public void SetHandPose(string poseName, float t = 1.0f)
        {
            var pose = m_preset[poseName];
            SetHandPose(ref pose, t);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set hand pose.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="poseIndex">index of pose in RuntimeHandPosePresetAsset.</param>
        /// <param name="t">lerp value of hand pose. 0.0f=base pose, 1.0f=poseName pose</param>
        public void SetHandPose(int poseIndex, float t = 1.0f)
        {
            var pose = m_preset[poseIndex];
            SetHandPose(ref pose, t);
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Set hand pose.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">hand pose</param>
        /// <param name="t">lerp value of hand pose. 0.0f=base pose, 1.0f=data</param>
        public void SetHandPose(ref HandPoseData data, float t = 1.0f)
        {
            if (m_runtimeControl == null)
            {
                InitializeRuntimeControl();
            }
            LerpHandPose(ref m_handPoseData, ref m_basePose, ref data, t);
        }

        private static void LerpHandPose(ref HandPoseData data, ref HandPoseData src, ref HandPoseData dst, float t)
        {
            switch (t)
            {
                case 0f:
                    data = src;
                    break;
                case 1.0f:
                    data = dst;
                    break;
                default:
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < HandPoseData.HumanFingerCount; ++i)
                    {
                        data[i] = new FingerPoseData
                        {
                            muscle1 = Mathf.Lerp(src[i].muscle1, dst[i].muscle1, t),
                            muscle2 = Mathf.Lerp(src[i].muscle2, dst[i].muscle2, t),
                            muscle3 = Mathf.Lerp(src[i].muscle3, dst[i].muscle3, t),
                            spread = Mathf.Lerp(src[i].spread, dst[i].spread, t)
                        };
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void InitializeRuntimeControl()
        {
            var animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            m_avatar = animator.avatar;

            if (m_avatar == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("HandController:Animator component doesn't have a valid avatar configured.");
            }
            
            m_runtimeControl = new HandRuntimeControl(gameObject, m_avatar, m_handType);
        }

        private void LateUpdate()
        {
            m_runtimeControl?.UpdateHandPose(ref m_handPoseData);
        }
    }
```

The next script is the HandType

In the enum I added the BothHands

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

    public enum HandType
    {
        LeftHand,
        RightHand,
        BothHands
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct FingerPoseData
    {
        [Range(-1f, 1f)]
        public float spread;
        [Range(-1f, 1f)]
        public float muscle1;
        [Range(-1f, 1f)]
        public float muscle2;
        [Range(-1f, 1f)]
        public float muscle3;
        
        public void WeightedAddPose(float weight, ref FingerPoseData data)
        {
            spread += weight * data.spread;
            muscle1 += weight * data.muscle1;
            muscle2 += weight * data.muscle2;
            muscle3 += weight * data.muscle3;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct HandPoseData
    {
        public FingerPoseData thumb;
        public FingerPoseData index;
        public FingerPoseData middle;
        public FingerPoseData ring;
        public FingerPoseData little;

        public const int HumanFingerCount = 5;
        
        public FingerPoseData this[int idx]
        {
            get
            {
                if (idx < 0 || idx >= HumanFingerCount)
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                }

                switch (idx)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return thumb;
                    case 1:
                        return index;
                    case 2:
                        return middle;
                    case 3:
                        return ring;
                    default:
                        return little;
                }
            }

            set
            {
                if (idx < 0 || idx >= HumanFingerCount)
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                }
                switch (idx)
                {
                    case 0:
                        thumb = value;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        index = value;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        middle = value;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ring = value;
                        break;
                    default:
                        little = value;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void WeightedAddPose(float weight, ref HandPoseData data)
        {
            thumb.WeightedAddPose(weight, ref data.thumb);
            index.WeightedAddPose(weight, ref data.index);
            middle.WeightedAddPose(weight, ref data.middle);
            ring.WeightedAddPose(weight, ref data.ring);
            little.WeightedAddPose(weight, ref data.little);
        }
    }

    public class HandRuntimeControl
    {
        private readonly int[] m_handBoneIndexMap;
        private readonly HumanPoseHandler m_poseHandler;
        private readonly GameObject m_rootObject;
        private HumanPose m_humanPose;

        public HandRuntimeControl(GameObject rootObject, Avatar avatar, HandType handType)
        {
            m_rootObject = rootObject;
            m_poseHandler = new HumanPoseHandler(avatar, rootObject.transform);
            m_handBoneIndexMap = new int[20];

            var indexMuscleFingerBegin = handType == HandType.LeftHand ? 55 : 75;
            
            m_poseHandler.GetHumanPose(ref m_humanPose);

            for (var i = 0; i < m_handBoneIndexMap.Length; ++i)
            {
                m_handBoneIndexMap[i] = indexMuscleFingerBegin + i;
            }
        }

        public void UpdateHandPose(ref HandPoseData handPose)
        {
            m_poseHandler.GetHumanPose(ref m_humanPose);
            
            m_humanPose.bodyPosition = Vector3.zero;
            m_humanPose.bodyRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            
            var i = 0;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.thumb.muscle1;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.thumb.spread;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.thumb.muscle2;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.thumb.muscle3;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.index.muscle1;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.index.spread;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.index.muscle2;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.index.muscle3;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.middle.muscle1;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.middle.spread;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.middle.muscle2;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.middle.muscle3;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.ring.muscle1;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.ring.spread;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.ring.muscle2;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.ring.muscle3;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.little.muscle1;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.little.spread;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.little.muscle2;
            m_humanPose.muscles[m_handBoneIndexMap[i++]] = handPose.little.muscle3;
            
            m_poseHandler.SetHumanPose(ref m_humanPose);
        }
    }
```

The last script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(HandController))]
public class InteractiveHandControllerAdapter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct InputConfig
    {
        public HandType hand;
        public string inputName;
        public int presetIndex;
    }

    [SerializeField] private InputConfig[] m_inputs;

    private HandController m_leftHand;
    private HandController m_rightHand;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        foreach (var c in GetComponents<HandController>())
        {
            if (c.Hand == HandType.LeftHand)
            {
                m_leftHand = c;
            }
            else
            {
                m_rightHand = c;
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (m_inputs != null)
        {
            foreach (var input in m_inputs)
            {
                if(input.hand == HandType.LeftHand) 
                    m_leftHand?.SetHandPose(input.presetIndex, Input.GetAxis(input.inputName));
                else 
                    m_rightHand?.SetHandPose(input.presetIndex, Input.GetAxis(input.inputName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its working fine when I change the enum in the editor or runtime for LeftHand or RightHand :

In the Inspector in this screenshot I selected the Left Hand I can change it to the Right Hand and it will affect the hands find but when changing to Both Hands it does nothing or keep changing only the left hand. I want it to change both hands when it's on the both hands enum mode.

[image: Hands controller script settings in inspector]

Comment: I'm not sure about this specific case so I'm not making this an answer, but note that you can have *both* values in an enum toggled on when it's being used for binary flags, rather than a standard variable. In other words, something like `hands = HandType.Left | HandType.Right;`

Comment: @jhocking Where do you make this line in what script and where ? I tried to replace the line [SerializeField] private HandType m_handType = HandType.LeftHand; TO [SerializeField] private HandType m_handType = HandType.LeftHand | HandType.RightHand; in HandController script. but it's not working still only each hand can be controlled individual.